# Why won't my else if or else function work when the first one does?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

I'm trying to use else/if statements to return different values based on what was clicked. Now, my code works for the first if, but suddenly does not for the rest. I can't understand why. Every button I have has a different ID, so when the button with the "small" ID is pressed, it changes the head1 to "Small". When the button with the "medium" Id is pressed, it does nothing, and continues to display "Small". Can anyone help the else if and else statement run?

```
document.querySelector(".pizza").addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (document.getElementById("small") == event.target) {
        Size_Price = 5;
        document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Small";
}       else if (document.getElementById("medium") == event.target) {
            Size_Price = 10;
            document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Medium";
}           else { 
                Size_Price = 18;
                document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Fatso"
}
})
```

Comment: @MisterJojo - event is a global - used to be IE only, but all other browsers do it now

Comment: Note: `document.querySelector(".pizza").addEventListener` only adds an event listener to the FIRST element with class `pizza` ... so, `.target` can only ever be equal to the first such element

Comment: You need querySelectorAll() and then loop over nodeLists

Comment: not necessarily ... @dalelandry

Comment: I **strongly** encourage you to use an explicit argument to receive the event for your event listener handler rather than the [legacy window extension](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-window-extensions) that defines the magic [Window `event` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).  e.g. `.addEventListener('click', function(event) { /* use event.target here */ ) });` instead of using `.addEventListener('click', function() { /* don't use event.target here */ ) });`

Answer (score 0):

Since you add the click handler to a single element, then `event.target` can only ever be that element.

Clearly you have 3 elements you want to add a handler to. You can either do one handler for each, or you can do something like this

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // check it's an element we're interested in
    if (event.target.classList.contains('pizza')) {
        if (document.getElementById("small") == event.target) {
            Size_Price = 5;
            document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Small";
        } else if (document.getElementById("medium") == event.target) {
            Size_Price = 10;
            document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Medium";
        } else {
            Size_Price = 18;
            document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Fatso"
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<div>
  Clicked on
  <span id="head1"></span>
</div>
<button id="small" class="pizza">Small</button>
<button id="medium" class="pizza">Medium</button>
<button id="fatso" class="pizza">Fatso</button>
```

Of course, you don't need to add the click handler to the `document` - just a common ancestor to the buttons (or whatever you use) will do

e.g.

```js
document.querySelector("main").addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(event.target.textContent);
    if (event.target.classList.contains('pizza')) {
        if (document.getElementById("small") == event.target) {
            Size_Price = 5;
            document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Small";
        } else if (document.getElementById("medium") == event.target) {
            Size_Price = 10;
            document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Medium";
        } else {
            Size_Price = 18;
            document.getElementById("head1").textContent = "Fatso"
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    Clicked on
    <span id="head1"></span>
  </div>
  <button id="small" class="pizza">Small</button>
  <button id="medium" class="pizza">Medium</button>
  <button id="fatso" class="pizza">Fatso</button>
</main>
<section>
  <button class="pizza">Ignored</button>
</section>
```

You can see, even though the "Ignored" button has the right class, it is ignored, since it's not inside the `main` element, where the click handler is being added

Comment: Man, you're an absolute lifesaver. God bless you!